Unable to extract 100k rows in single select query from apache ignite in less than 20sec from a 100MB table
I am running apache ignite on kubernetes cluster in azure.I have loaded in memory table of 100MB size with 400k rows.
Cluster is Standard_B4ms and is running on 5 nodes and 5 replicas of ignite.
Is there any way i can reduce the select query response time from 22sec to less than 5sec.
Could you please guide me here?
I have tried running below queries
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS txn_100mb_4colns;
CREATE TABLE txn_100mb_4colns (
    dept_id VARCHAR,
    store_id VARCHAR,
    week_id VARCHAR,
    sales DECIMAL(10, 2),
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_id,week_id,store_id)
) WITH "template=partitioned, backups=1, affinityKey=dept_id, CACHE_NAME=txn_100mb_4colns,KEY_TYPE=demo.model.txn_100mb_4colns_key, VALUE_TYPE=demo.model.txn_100mb_4colns";
create index txn_100mb_4colns_index1 on txn_100mb_4colns (week_id,dept_id,store_id) INLINE_SIZE 13;
COPY
FROM
'C:\Users\koushik\Downloads\txn_100mb_4colns.csv'
INTO
    txn_100mb_4colns (
    dept_id ,
    store_id ,
    week_id,
    sales
    ) FORMAT CSV
    

Query i am executing:
SELECT week_id, dept_id, store_id, sales
FROM txn_100mb_4colns
WHERE WEEK_ID = '202101'
ORDER BY sales DESC
LIMIT 100000


Try indexing these columns in this order in your covering index.
(week_id, sales DESC, dept_id, store_id) 

This should allow your DBMS to deliver its result set without a separate sort step.

Thanks Jones for the response. Would this be able to deliver the required performance?

Maybe? Give it a try? This kind of performance depends on many many things.

There are soo many items to address here, so let's start with the likelihood that your query process is bounded by the result set size! When you issue a query that returns many rows (and returns lots of data KB, MB) regardless of how many nodes you have, the process is bounded by the 1 host that has to retrieve and do whatever with the result data. There is no way around this because this is a pure network data transfer problem. But what about other things: You are using dept_id as an affinity key. How many distinct dept_id's are there? Hopefully there are thousands not 10's. Are the dept_id's approximately equally distributed among your data set? If not then you will have more data on some nodes than on others. Your key columns are all VARCHAR. Be aware that numeric values are generally easier to compare and to index. As such you might consider converting VARCHAR values to numeric values for improved comparison. This however would be the least impactful of the above items. Hope that helps.

Yes, the dept_ids are in thousands and are distributed equally. I did try setting the week_id as the distribution yet i am getting the same response time of 22sec. I will consider the conversion of varchar to numeric.Thanks for that.
